# Adding a list of lists as a column to an existing dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a list of the type:

```
hashes = [[earthquake], [terrible, help, emergency], [disaster], [funny, happy], [lol]]
```

And a dataframe of the type:

```
data = {'ID': ['0','1','2','3', '4'], 'Text': ['I felt an earthquake!','New York City needs help immediately!','A look at the situation in the U.S.','I had a great day!', 'Just chilliiiiing']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Text'])
```

Image of dataframe:

[image: Dataframe image]

I want to add this list as a separate column called "Hashes" to the dataframe above, with each list being added as a separate row. For a normal list of terms I would simply do this:

```
df['hashes'] = hashes
```

However, doing this for a list of lists is giving me a "Length of values does not match length of index" error due to the varying list length. What is the right way to proceed?

Comment: Can you add a sample of your original dataframe to this question?

Comment: I added one to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need `df.append`

```
import pandas as pd

hashes = [["earthquake"], ["terrible", "help", "emergency"], ["disaster"], ["funny", "happy"], ["lol"]]
df = pd.DataFrame({"hashes": [1, 2,3]})

print(df)
print(df.append(pd.DataFrame({"hashes":hashes})))
```

**Output:**

```
   hashes
0       1
1       2
2       3
```

---

```
                        hashes
0                            1
1                            2
2                            3
0                 [earthquake]
1  [terrible, help, emergency]
2                   [disaster]
3               [funny, happy]
4                        [lol]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but instead of appending to an existing column could you please show how to add the list as an entirely new one?

Comment: oh ok...`df['hashes'] = hashes` should work. You are getting `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index` because the length of `hashes` and your `df` do not match. You are probably missing some data

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are planning to do with the information you have, if you just want to store the info, you can turn the list of lists into a string and save it inside the dataframe.

If you want to query those infos I would suggest a different data structures to allow the queries to be made performactly.

Do you want to query those infos?

Comment: I would like to query it yes. Each list in the list of lists called hashes corresponds to the hashtags present in a single tweet. I want to use the presence of specific hash tags to predict the sentiment in the tweets.